# Performing math.sqrt on numpy structured array column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math.sqrt

I have a numpy structured array. The final column needs to contain the result of a simple math equation based on the other values in the row. Problem is I get the following error when trying to calculate the square root portion of the equation:

`TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Limitation is that I cannot iterate the array to add the values one at a time.

Here's an example to show the error:

```
import numpy as np
import math

data = np.random.randint(-100, 100, (1, 6, 4))

data[:,3] = math.sqrt((0-data[:,0])**2 + (0-data[:,1])**2 + (0-data[:,2])**2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to use `np.sqrt` instead of `math.sqrt` (the latter only works on single values).

Comment: Silly me! Thanks for picking that up.